# Inserting custom string inside value parameter of a button

Tags: php, html

Hello I am trying to insert custom string inside button Value, but I am facing a problem when I inster the string inside the `value` parameter the string is appering like text instead as a valuer="" inside the button string. Here is my button code:

```
$buttons = '<input type="submit" name="Submit" style="width:110px;margin:0 auto;display:block;"  value="'.pll_e('message','wpnotification').'" />' ;
```

So basicaly I need when this is rendered the result of the function to be shown inside the `input button` not outside

Instead of the result of this to be `<input type="submit" name="Submit" style="width:110px;margin:0 auto;display:block;"  value="String Text">`

The result is:

```
String Text
<input type="submit" name="Submit" style="width:110px;margin:0 auto;display:block;"  value="">
```

So I need this text to apper inside the value tag.

Comment: _"the string is appering like text instead as a valuer="" inside the button string."_  What?!?!

Comment: I think i know what the problem is. `pll_e()` function must be `echoing` the output instead of `returning` it.

Comment: Latheesan this was the problem you can post it as a answer and I will accept it.

Comment: all done.. with a little explanation too. see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into answer...

I think i know what the problem is. `pll_e()` function must be echoing the output instead of `returning` it.

Your function must look something similar to this:

```
function pll_e($paramA, $paramB) {
    echo $paramA . " " . $paramB;
}
```

If that's the case, then you can deal with it by capturing the output buffer to a variable and use it on the button like this:

```
ob_start();
pll_e('message','wpnotification');
$funcValue = ob_get_clean();

$buttons = '<input type="submit" name="Submit" style="width:110px;margin:0 auto;display:block;"  value="'. $funcValue .'" />';
```

---

Alternatively, if you have access to the `pll_e` function... then just change it, so it `return` the value instead of `echo` it like this (example):

```
function pll_e($paramA, $paramB) {
    return $paramA . " " . $paramB;
}

$buttons = '<input type="submit" name="Submit" style="width:110px;margin:0 auto;display:block;"  value="'. pll_e('message','wpnotification') .'" />' ;
```